# SQL best match between two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, match

I am looking to find best matching record between two tables
e.g

```
Tbl_Proddesc values
Prod_desc
    xxabcd123
    xxxabcde345
    xabcAAA
```

---

```
Tbl_Prod values
Prod
    abc
    abcd
    abcde
```

---

I want to return from table 1 the value "xxabcd123" and from the the product table "abcd" which is close match between them

```
Expected Result
Prod desc    Prod
---------    -----
xxabcd123    abcd
```

Any ideas how to get close match?

The SQL I tried not getting the result

```
SELECT top 1 pd.Prod_desc,p.prod
from Tbl_Proddesc pd
left outer join Tbl_Prod p
where pd.Prod_desc like '%' + p.prod + '%'
order by len(p.prod) asc
```

Many thanks.

Comment: You seem to be missing a join condition?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [SOUNDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/soundex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function.

```
SELECT top 1 
     pd.Prod_desc
    ,p.prod 
FROM Tbl_Proddesc pd
LEFT OUTER JOIN Tbl_Prod p 
    ON SOUNDEX(pd.Prod_desc) = SOUNDEX(p.prod ) 
ORDER BY len(p.prod) ASC
```

Comment: Thank you all , your comments were really useful still can't get 100% match because when ordering by len(prod)  either way asc or desc it matching wrongly still some values as i got data like abc,abcd,abcde which when matching with description will bring wrong results someway but much better match now

Answer (score 0):

Your query is very much on the right track.  You just want a *descending* sort -- and to phrase the `join` correctly:

```
select top 1 pd.Prod_desc,p.prod
from Tbl_Proddesc pd left outer join
     Tbl_Prod p
     on pd.Prod_desc like '%' + p.prod + '%'
order by len(p.prod) desc;
```

Note:  You can also use:

```
order by p.prod desc
```

Longer strings are "bigger" than shorter strings, when the longer string starts with the shorter string.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `SOUNDEX` for text comparisons.  Comparisons of `SOUNDEX` values are accomplished using the `DIFFERENCE` function.  In this case to make sure you're comparing every row in Tbl_Proddesc to every row in Tbl_Prod the query uses `OUTER APPLY` (which is effectively a `CROSS JOIN`).  For the example given the `SOUNDEX` values are the same across all 3 possibilities.  To decide which string is closest we would need the specific algorithm to use.  If ties are acceptable (and a random matching row) then `WITH TIES` could be removed from the query.

```
drop table if exists #Tbl_Proddesc;
drop table if exists #Tbl_Prod;
go
create table #Tbl_Proddesc(
  prod_desc     varchar(40) not null);
create table #Tbl_Prod(
  prod_desc     varchar(40) not null);

insert #Tbl_Proddesc(prod_desc) values
    ('xxabcd123'),
    ('xxxabcde345'),
    ('xabcAAA');    

insert #Tbl_Prod(prod_desc) values
    ('abc'),
    ('abcd'),
    ('abcde');    

select t.prod_desc, top_x.*
from #Tbl_Proddesc t
     outer apply (select top 1 with ties
                         x.prod_desc,
                         difference(t.prod_desc, x.prod_desc) sx_diff
                  from #Tbl_Prod x
                  order by sx_diff) top_x;
```

```
prod_desc   prod_desc   sx_diff
xxabcd123   abc         2
xxabcd123   abcd        2
xxabcd123   abcde       2
xxxabcde345 abc         2
xxxabcde345 abcd        2
xxxabcde345 abcde       2
xabcAAA     abcd        2
xabcAAA     abcde       2
```